# what does this x86_64 asm code do?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, reverse-engineering, virtual-functions

This is from 64-bit Linux shared object:

```
mov     rax, [rbp+var_1C+4]
mov     rax, [rax]
add     rax, 8
mov     rax, [rax]
mov     rdx, [rbp+var_1C+4]
mov     rdi, rdx
call    rax
```

Comment: That is almost impossible to tell. Oh, you can see which values are begin moved around, but it is impossible to say what that is supposed to achieve without the context. **I guess** this prepares a function call (possibly a virtual function call, where *rax* contains the address of the virtual function and *rdi* a pointer to the instance, i.e.*this*/*self*/<whatever it is called>). Or it calls a method of an interface. Or...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a virtual function call.

Looks like un-optimized compiler output, given the usage of `rbp` as a frame pointer, and using `add rax,8` instead of an addressing mode like `mov rax, [rax+8]`.  And the reload of the local for no reason when it could have kept the pointer live in a register after loading it earlier.

It looks like it's preparing a `this` pointer as an arg for the virtual function, as well as calling a virtual function through the vtable.  [How do objects work in x86 at the assembly level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556511/how-do-objects-work-in-x86-at-the-assembly-level)

Anyway **this code is just an inefficient way of writing**

```
mov    rdi, [rbp+var_1C+4]    # load a pointer to a local from the stack
mov    rax, [rdi]             # load the vtable pointer from the start of the object
call   [rax+8]                # index into the vtable
```

Or maybe setting `rdx` was intended, rather than just inefficient un-optimized code.  In the x86-64 System V ABI, `rdx` holds the 3rd integer / pointer arg to function calls.  `rdi` holds the first (including `this` as a hidden first arg).  If `rsi` was set earlier, then perhaps `rdx` is being passed intentionally, so it's a call like `foo->virtual_function(something, foo)`, where `class something *foo` is a local variable or function arg.

Otherwise it's just `foo->virtual_function()`.

---

Or it's something completely different that just happens to look like what a compiler would emit for a virtual function call.  You can't know without more context.

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation! Just was I was looking for.