# What is a functions list pointer at beginning of structure called c++

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering, powerpc

I'm reversing some assembly code and I'm consistently coming across certain structures that have an address at the very beginning of the structure.

This address seems to be a pointer to the beginning of an array of function addresses related to that specific structure.

I've also noticed that the first function in the array is usually related to deallocated/cleaning up of the structure.

Does anyone know what this type of structuring is called? I'd like to learn how this works

Comment: You might be looking at a pointer to a vtable (virtual table).

Comment: Virtual table. For virtual functions. Such as a destructor or user-defined virtual function. As these are run-time dependent. Try reverse-engineering of a class/struct that has no virtual functions. See the difference. Or also interesting: inheritance with virtual tables.

Comment: [How do objects work in x86 at the assembly level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33556511) shows how the vtable works, with x86 examples of compiler-generated code.

Comment: Would the first function in the vtable be the destructor?

Comment: It's implementation dependent. Linux and Windows implement their vtable in exactly the opposite order (it depends on the order of declaration IIRC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the "vtable" a.k.a. ["virtual method table"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).