# How does polymorphism with multiple inheritance work in assembly?

Tags: assembly, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, vtable, static-polymorphism

so I believe I understand polymorphism with single inheritance, where say you have classes Dog and Cat inherit from an interface Animal and Animal has a Speak and Walk function so then you generate v tables for Dog and Cat, both having a function pointer to their respective Speak and Walk functions, and if I’m calling a general one of those functions for a general Animal, assembly will grab the first data member of the Animal which is a pointer to the v table, dereference it, then add the correct offset to get the correct function pointer, then call said function at the memory address.

So my question is how would this work for multiple inheritance.  So for the example, I will do Dog and Cat inheriting from interfaces Animal and Colorable: Animal will have functions Speak and Walk, and Colorable will have GetColor and SetColor.  Would Dog have have a v table to Animal functions and then a v table to Colorable functions? Would that mean that every Colorable class would have memory padding so that way its v table is the second member so that you can do polymorphism with Colorable?  Or would you have a triple pointer pointing to a table of v table pointers so that you only have class instances of the memory padding as opposed to object instances?  Wouldn’t dereferencing a triple pointer be slow?

Is there another memory schema that I’m not considering?  I haven’t found many good resources on this.

I know C#, Java, Rust, etc. supports polymorphism with multiple inheritance, so I feel like this is a solved thing.

I have tried searching on YouTube and stack overflow and Google, none of which have given me good results.  I did find a page regarding Java doing multiple inheritance but to me it was kind of cryptic and hard to understand.

Edit:
To add clarification, I’m looking specifically for single layered inheritance, like Rust’s trait syntax.  Regarding C# and Java multiple inheritance, I am referring to the ability to use multiple interfaces for an object and be able to use said interface as a type for static polymorphism.  Rust allows for implementing multiple traits.

Comment: None of those languages support multiple inheritance in the way you're suggesting.

`C# does not support multiple inheritance of classes, but it does support multiple inheritance using interfaces.`

`Multiple Inheritance is ... inherits more than one superclass. Java does not support Multiple Inheritance;`

`Rust also does not use class inheritance so problems like diamond patterns cannot exist...`

Perhaps try revisiting how single-inheritance is implemented in these languages. The semantic inconsistency of multiple class inheritance is why implementations of it are generally avoided.

Comment: @EdNutting in my question, I used interfaces instead of classes or abstract classes.  Rust uses the trait system as opposed to interfaces or classes that you can inherit, but replace Animal and Colorable with traits and you can have a Vec<dyn Animal> and Vec<dyn Colorable>.  Java you can implement multiple interfaces, C# as well.  And you can do static polymorphism with all these implementations.  I guess I’m specifically looking at Rust’s implementation where inheritance can only be one layer deep, to avoid diamond cases.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Stroustrup covers how this is (can be) done in his `The C++ Programming Language`, but I don't remember the details - it's complicated. Your understanding of how inheritance and virtual methods work in single inheritance is correct, and with multiple interfaces you have a VMT for each interface.

Comment: Thank you for the resource.  It seems like a really good book.  I managed to skim through Section 21-22 which cover class hierarchy and multiple inheritance and unfortunately does not discuss how it works under the hood as far as I can tell.

Comment: This essentially runs headlong into a terminology problem - you're saying "inheritance" but the proper word is "implement". Implementing multiple interfaces is not the same thing as inheriting from multiple classes.

Comment: To implement multiple interfaces, you either have a single class that happens to implement all the methods, or you have a class with single inheritance from a single base class, which together all of the interface methods. Some of the base classes' methods may be overridden by the child class.

Comment: Thus you never have multiple inheritance. You only ever have the single inheritance situation, which you've already understood.

All the "multiple interface" stuff (mostly) gets elided by the (JIT) compiler.

Comment: Relevant related question/answer that explains C++ virtual calls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556511/how-do-objects-work-in-x86-at-the-assembly-level

Answer (score 4):

None of the languages you say implement inheritance in the way you describe. You are describing C++ - it's in C++ you have a pointer to vtable at the beginning of a class.

In C++, the first base class gets merged with the derived: the vtable pointer in the beginning of the Dog is also a vtable pointer for the inscribed Animal base class (if Animal is first). The vtable would start with Animal virtual functions (`Speak`, `Walk`), then other base classes functions (`GetColor`, `SetColor`), then other virtual finctions of Dog, if any.

All other base classes will have a different vtable. That means the inscribed Colorable vtable pointer will point to a **different** vtable of Dog - the one that has `GetColor` and `SetColor` first. Moreover, those virtual functions will **not be the same** as the ones in the main vtable! They would be a special versions, that correct the pointer first (to point on Dog instance, instead of the inscribed Colorable instance).

In Java, there is a vtable for each base interface, and the runtime does a search in the list of interfaces to find a correct one. It is pretty much the same in C#, with minor differences. The JIT-compiler can optimize that, if needed.

In Rust, there are no pointers to vtable inside the "classes" at all. Instead, Rust uses "fat pointers" for the interfaces themselves - references to the interface are double sized, because they contain two pointers: one for the object, one for the vtable. The pointer to the vtable is only produced when you convert an object to a `&dyn Interface` type - not before. The pointer points to the correct position inside the vtable, so the current interface functions will appear first:

- `&dyn Animal` will be equal `{&Dog, &Dog_vtable + 0}`,
- `&dyn Colorable` will be equal `{&Dog, &Dog_vtable + 16}`, etc

Comment: C# compiles it into intermediate language by which point the interface and class information has been fully resolved (notwithstanding dynamic loading.) The backend of the compiler ("JIT") typically forms a single vtable for each concrete class. There's no need of "searching through a list of vtables". AFAIK, the JIT for Java solved this the same way a long time ago (circa 2010.) (Side note: This is why the myth of interfaces be slow no longer holds.)

Re C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556511/how-do-objects-work-in-x86-at-the-assembly-level